# How do I install FreeCAD without having it crash when opened?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa

I am new to Linux and am looking for a CAD software to design a part for my honors thesis. I am interested in the GUI aspect of the software.

I followed the instructions for installing FreeCAD on their wiki using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install freecad
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable
sudo apt-get update
```

The program appeared to install fine, but when I open the program and attempt to switch from the start workbench to the draft workbench, the program crashes. I get the following message in the terminal:

```
Persistent toolbars: Snapper toolbar not managed.
free(): invalid next size (normal)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I suspect I haven't installed the program correctly, and I am unsure how to fix it from this point. On the Wiki there is the command

```
ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable
```

which is suppose to be ran at "Ubuntu Software Centre > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software", but I don't know where to find this directory.

Here is the wiki I have been following:

https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Install_on_Unix

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and this is the output when started from the command line:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f418f70df20]
```

If I first select draft then open a new document.
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Why are you adding an (unnecessary) PPA *after* you have already installed freecad?

Comment: I haven't done this before, I thought it was part of the installation process for freecad so it knows where packages are located.

Comment: Hmmm. Were there any errors when you installed FreeCad? Debs are designed to be rather foolproof - it takes a lot of work to mess up installing a deb. Which release of Ubuntu are you using? Try starting FreeCad from the command line, and copy/paste the complete output into your Question above.

Comment: Yes, please do as @user535733 has asked since it would help us figure the problem faster.

Comment: I would recommend to:  1. Deinstall FreeCAD, `sudo apt remove freecad` , 2. Remove the PPA, 3. `sudo apt update`, 4. Install FreeCAD, `sudo apt install freecad`